# Excel - count first adjacent non-zero and not-null values in a row

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a formula, which will count numbers (>0) in a row.

Only the first set of >0 numbers in a row should be counted.

When there is a 0 or an empty cell after the >0 number, the count should ignore next values.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why row 3 result is 2 and row 6 result is 2?

Comment: row 3 - first >0 number is 1 and next one is 2. Count is 2. row 6 - first >0 number is 2, next one is 3. Count is 2.

Comment: @ManishChristian I believe because in row 3 there are a total of 2 numbers that are greater than 0, and in row 6 there are 2 numbers that are greater than 0.

Comment: Got it now. My brain needed some coffee :)

Comment: @chilliq - Is a user defined function in VBA an option? This would be quite simple in VBA

Comment: @Absinthe it's an option - I have no idea how to do this with formulas...

Comment: @chilliq - Glad you said that, I couldn't come up with anything just using formulas ;) VBA answer on its way, though would be interesting to see if anyone can do this with native formulas

Comment: @Absinthe: it boiled my brain, but see below :)

Comment: @RADO - Nice one. Can you explain a bit more in your answer how it works?

Comment: @Absinthe: Done

Comment: @RADO Clever stuff, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [UDF](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) so you can loop through the columns from left to right. Place the following code in a module and use it like any other formula. It has one arguement - the range of cells on the row.

```
Function CountAdjacent(rng As Range)

Dim x As Integer, result As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim firstValuePassed As Boolean


Set ws = rng.Parent

For x = rng.Column To rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
    If ws.Cells(rng.Row, x) <> 0 And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rng.Row, x)) Then
        result = result + 1
        firstValuePassed = True
    Else
        If firstValuePassed = True Then Exit For
    End If
Next x

CountAdjacent = result

End Function
```

How it works:
The For loop on x goes from the first selected column to the last. If it encounters a number it increments the result by one and flags that a number has been encountered in the firstValuePassed boolean, since you want any gaps in the numbers to stop the count. If it encounters a zero or blank cell it checks against firstValuePassed to see if it comes after a number >0, if so it stops the count, if not it moves to the next cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, the formula is ok but in my file in empty cells are defined formulas, Which causes that the function counts also cells which looks empty- is there a possibility to solve it?

Comment: Sure, just add And ws.Cells(rng.Row, x).Formula <> "" to the If statement

Answer (score 2):

It was fun trying to figure out a non-VBA solution.

1) Enter formula in cell H3:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B3),COLUMN(B3)+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B3:E3>0,0),0)-1)
```

It will generate a cell adress ("D3") which contains the first value > 0 in its row.

2) Enter formula in cell I3:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDIRECT(H3):F3=0,0),0)-1
```

It will give you the expected result:

[image]

Requirement: one cell immediately after the data (F3) must be empty.

**[Edit]: How it works**

Approach logic:

1. for each record, find the address of the first cell that contains value > 0
2. starting from this cell address, find position of the first cell that is zero or blank
3. Desired count is a position number found at step 2, less 1

For example, for the first record step one gives "D3" - cell of the first value. Step 2 calculates that the first cell without value after "D3" starts in position 3 (D3 has value, E3 has value, F3 is blank). Therefore, value count is 3 - 1 = 2 (values in D3 and E3).

How formulas work:
INDEX(B3:E3>0,0) compares every cell in range B3:E3 to 0 (blanks are treated as 0s), and returns results as a boolean array {FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE}. MATCH(TRUE, ...) then finds position of the first TRUE in this array (3). ADDRESS calculates cell adress by adding this position to cell B3 ("B+3, 3" = "D3") .

INDIRECT(H3):F3 takes cell address we calculated in the first formula ("D3") from cell H3, and generates range D3:F3. Then MATCH(INDEX()) goes over this range and finds a position of the first cell without value (3) after D3. So, we have value in first position (D3), second position (E3), and no value in 3rd position (F3). 3 - 1 = 2 positions with values.